# Adding data to factory @ angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have the following factory which works. But I want to add data to the factory and I have no clue how to do it..

Thanks for the help !

```
app.factory('Favorites', function($http, $q){
    var factory = {
        artists : false,
        getArtists : function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if(factory.artists !== false){
                console.log('true');
                deferred.resolve(factory.artists);
            }else{
                console.log('false');

                $http.get('https://homechefhome.fr/rise/favorites-artists.php?user_id=10155092792384782')
                    .success(function(data, status){
                        // if everything is good, we save data in factory
                        factory.artists = data;
                        console.log('L55', factory.artists, status);
                        deferred.resolve(factory.artists);
                    }).error(function(data, status){
                        deferred.reject('No data collected');
                        console.log('L59', data, status);
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
    return factory;
});
```

Comment: What kind of data do you want to add, and under what circumstances would you add it?

Comment: What do you mean adding data ? Can you elaborate

Comment: Are you trying to add additional data to what is being returned by the factory?  Like additional fields or something?

Comment: factory.artists contains the artists I have added to my playlist.
they are stored in a database.
So when I open the page containing my playlist, it displays the artists, but I want to add new artists to my playlist.
I can do that from another view/controller.

So I want to know, how can I add data (an artist object) to factory.artists

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to "add" the data to your application you must reference the factory and getArtists function in your controller. Something like this should do the trick:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, Artists) { 
    $scope.artists = Artists.getArtists();
    console.log($scope.artists);
});
```

If that's not what you were looking for let me know and I'll revise my answer.

Comment: With that, I only get data, but I cannot add to Artists.getArtists() right ?

Let's say, I have 4 artists in my factory, but I would like to add one more, what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically,

by adding this line : factory.artists.push({myobj:'helloworld'});
I can actually add the object, but i want to do that from the view/controller.

```
 $http.get('https://homechefhome.fr/rise/favorites-artists.php?user_id=10155092792384782')
   .success(function(data, status){
   // if everything is good, we save data in factory
   factory.artists = data;


   factory.artists.push({myobj:'helloworld'});//add an object, I want to do that from a controller, another view


    console.log('ligne 55',factory.artists, status);
    deferred.resolve(factory.artists);
 }).error(function(data, status){
    deferred.reject('No data collected');
    console.log('ligne 59', data, status);
 });
```

This is the code from the controller : (it doesn't work)

```
$scope.addFavoriteArtist = function(){
    Favorites.getArtists().then(function(){
        Favorites.factory.push({hello:'Controller'});
    });
};
```

It says : Cannot read property 'push' of undefined